# Randomly picking a user defined number of text from a list with php

Tags: php, random

I'm quite new to php and trying to create a little website where a user can enter a list of values (preferrably from an excel address list) and the amount of random values he wants. I then want to pick this amount random values from this list with php.

In the end I want to be able to enter a list of participants of a contest and pick a defined amount of winners with checking if they've already been chosen.

Google and this website always gave me results on how to randomly pick numbers or how to generate values.

What would be the best way to do this? One tip on how to start would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Read book. Try to write code. Come back with problems

Comment: Convert it to an list i.e array and use `array_rand()` function to randomize it.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly what you are trying to ask then you could use -

[Random function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

```
    <?php
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
?>
```